# Automatically load drivers in Windows 10 Unattended installation

Tags: drivers, winpe

I have an unattended Windows 10 installer on a USB drive, but I need to load some drivers for a particular laptop model so setup can see the internal SSD.  So far, I have found the "amd64_Microsoft-Windows-PnpCustomizationsWinPE" component, but I still don't have something right, I think probably with the Key and Path values.

This is an offline install USB, so I need the driver to reside locally on the USB.  So far, I have created a "Drivers" folder at the root of the USB drive, and I have tried referencing it with "X:\Drivers", "D:\Drivers", etc.  I am also not 100% sure what it's looking for in the "Key" value, but I have tried "Path1", "1", etc with no luck.

Comment: What driver do you believe you need to streamline into your ISO to use a SSD? Windows 10 does and should have all the required drivers built into the WinPE required to install Windows. Trying to solve what likely is your actual problem since solving that will answer this question also.

Comment: Make and model of hardware may be good to know. Sounds like an RAID ON vs AHCI thing I was dragged into once to help the PC techs with a new model Dell laptop that hosed up post image push. That was for imaging though and was related to embedding some specific driver downloaded from hardware vendor site to a WIM I believe. I'm sure I have some notes if you determine it's related but hardware make and model may be of importance as well as UEFI settings iirc. We go with AHCI for the most part nowadays since then iirc but don't deal with workstations often these days (only when they need my help)

Comment: Only driver that Windows would require is a RAID driver, and only if, you install Windows to a RAID which i absolutely cannot recommend since most people end up issuing a RAID configuration that doesn’t support limited drive failures. author makes it sound like a single SSD though.

Comment: I recommend downloading NTLite (https://www.ntlite.com). This app allows you to slipstream a windows install with GUI. Its then a matter of just adding the driver there and it'll do everything for you. Once you have an ISO, use rufus to create the USB drive.